# What equations are in Python Gekko flowsheet objects?

Tags: python, gekko, process-control

What are the equations and other details of the [built-in Python Gekko flowsheet objects](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chemical.html#flowsheet-objects) such as the reactor model? Gekko has the compounds that I need for an industrial application of nonlinear Model Predictive Control (MPC) to a gas-phase fluidized-bed polymer (polyethylene) reactor.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO, chemical
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
c = chemical.Properties(m)
c.compound('ethylene')    # primary monomer reactant
c.compound('propylene')   # co-polymer monomer reactant
c.compound('hydrogen')    # melt-index modifier
c.compound('ethane')      # inert
c.compound('propane')     # inert
c.compound('cyclohexene') # density modifier
c.compound('isopentane')  # condensing agent
c.compound('nitrogen')    # pressure control
f = chemical.Flowsheet(m)
r = f.reactor(ni=2)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()
```

This simple reactor model produces the following output:

```py
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  1
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  12
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  12
   Equations    :  0
   Residuals    :  0

 Number of state variables:    29
 Number of total equations: -  10
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    19

 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------

 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  2.55529E-16  1.38889E+00
    1  2.38753E-25  1.23358E-16
    2  2.38753E-25  1.23358E-16
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.026300000000000004 sec
 Objective      :  0.
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

How can I find more details about the 10 equations and 29 variables? I am interested in property control (melt index and density) and maximize production rate by adjusting catalyst, hydrogen, and co-monomer (propylene, iso-butene, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Gekko outputs a LaTeX file `rto_4_latex.tex` (or `{mode}_4_latex.tex}` for [other modes](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Modes)) with the model details about equations and variables when you set `m.options.DIAGLEVEL` to 4 or higher.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO, chemical
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
c = chemical.Properties(m)
c.compound('ethylene')    # primary monomer reactant
c.compound('propylene')   # co-polymer monomer reactant
c.compound('hydrogen')    # melt-index modifier
c.compound('ethane')      # inert
c.compound('propane')     # inert
c.compound('cyclohexene') # density modifier
c.compound('isopentane')  # condensing agent
c.compound('nitrogen')    # pressure control
f = chemical.Flowsheet(m)
r = f.reactor(ni=2)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 4
m.solve()
m.open_folder()
```

You can also see more information in the many files that it produces when you solve locally with `remote=False` and open the run directory with `m.open_folder()`.

```latex
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Model Title}
\author{John D. Hedengren}
\maketitle
\section{equations}

\subsection{Equation 1 }
\texttt{ ss.reactor1.overall\_mole\_balance }
\begin{equation}
0 = {\dot n}_{in} + {\dot r}_{gen} - {\dot n}_{out} - \frac{\partial n}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
Variables
\begin{enumerate}
\item \texttt{ 0.60000E+00 kmol/sec    ss.reactor1.inlet[1].ndot * 2}
\item \texttt{ 0.60000E+00 kmol/sec    ss.reactor1.inlet[2].ndot * 11}
\item \texttt{ 0.12000E+01 kmol/sec    ss.reactor1.outlet.ndot * 19}
\item \texttt{ 0.00000E+00 kmol/sec    ss.v1 * 29}
\end{enumerate}
```

You can get a PDF document if you compile the LaTeX document with `call pdflatex main` if you are in Windows and have [downloaded texlive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/). Otherwise, you could put it into the [online OverLeaf editor](https://www.overleaf.com/) to convert to a PDF. Here are the first two equations of the 7 page document that is created.

[image: PDF of Gekko Model]

Comment: How hard would it be to make Gekko output Microsoft Word document? I'm guessing that it wouldn't be easy. It looks like a powerful way to build the model documentation as a PDF. A lot of the people I interact with only want to use Excel, Word, and e-mail.

Comment: Equations are a lot easier to write with LaTeX although I've seen more LaTeX equation support in recent versions of Word. I'll see if something is available for automatic export. Others may also be able to point me to some resources.